# Flutter Does Not Recognize Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3

Tags: flutter, android-studio-3.0

Literary, just started looking at Flutter, installed the Flutter plug in in Android Studio 3.0.1, restarted Android Studio, created a simple hello world app according to Flutter documentation.

This also installed Flutter SDK in `C:\flutter`, so app creation process selected that location for SDK location correctly.

However, running app (on emulator), shows me this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Finished with error: 

* Error running Gradle:
Unable to download needed Android SDK components, as the following licenses have not been accepted:
Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3

To resolve this, please run the following command in a Terminal:
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

But when I look in Android SDK, every Build-Tools from `25.0.0 to 27.0.1` is installed including `25.0.3.`

Running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` from terminal as suggested above shows this error

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\work\flutter\first_flutter_app>doctor --android-licences
'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

**UPDATE**

Then I added my `C:\flutter\bin` to system path and tried again issuing

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

but got error "`Unknown argument --licenses`".

Next I run:

```
flutter upgrade
```

this completed, too but running my app still produced same error re license issue.

`flutter upgrade` shows following output:

```
Running flutter doctor...
[√] Flutter (on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063], locale en-US, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision d957c8f040 (4 days ago), 2017-11-30 13:29:59 -0800
    • Engine revision 77d8acb9be
    • Tools Dart version 1.25.0-dev.11.0
    • Engine Dart version 2.0.0-dev.9.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 25.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    • Unable to locate Android NDK.

    • Unable to locate compiler in Android NDK.

    • Platform android-25, build-tools 25.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)
```

I literaly keep going in circles with this.  Here is what happens when I run my app from terminall using flutter (above I explained what happens if I run it from the IDE:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\work\flutter\flutter_app_myapp>flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                0.7s
Resolving dependencies...                                |

* Error running Gradle:
Unable to download needed Android SDK components, as the following licenses have not been accepted:
Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3

To resolve this, please run the following command in a Terminal:
flutter doctor --android-licenses                                                                                                        /
C:\Users\user\Desktop\work\flutter\flutter_app_myapp>>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Unknown argument --licenses
```

**UPDATE2**

Output of `flutter -v doctor --android-licenses`

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\work\flutter\flutter_app_dino>flutter -v doctor --android-licenses
[  +23 ms] [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/alpha
[        ] [C:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +20 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] alpha
[        ] [C:\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +19 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] [C:\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +20 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] d957c8f040902aa3fd44b367150bde56b64cec83
[        ] [C:\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +21 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 5 days ago
[ +222 ms] C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses
**Error: Unknown argument --licenses**
Usage:
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] \
    [--package_file <package-file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]

In its first form, installs, or uninstalls, or updates packages.
    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
     with explicit paths.
In its second form (with --update), currently installed packages are
    updated to the latest version.
In its third form, all installed and available packages are printed out.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK containing this tool
    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.
    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.
    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.
    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.
    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.

* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS.
[ +152 ms] "flutter doctor" took 301ms.
[ +198 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 196ms
[   +2 ms] exiting with code 0
```

However, if I navigate to my Android\sdk\tools\bin, I do have sdkmanager and issuing `sdkmanager --licenses` from there shows:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin>sdkmanager --licenses
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

So, it looks like Flutter is full of bugs at the moment, not sure if it is worth spending time with it at this alpha stage, as you can see, I have several circular problems where it says it cannot find a command, but the command exists.  I followed exact installation steps and if it takes days to figure it out and still have no solution, I'd say, it is not even close to being ready.

Comment: Have you tried to run `<Android SDK>/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses` and accept the license ?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and accepted all licenses, restarted Android Studio and emulator and have the same issue as I described in my post above

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14942#issuecomment-369319232 might be related

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this error when running `flutter doctor` is because you didn't put the flutter.bat location file in your PATH (Windows environment variable). Or maybe flutter just screwed up. 
Let's say you don't wanna do it, just refer to `flutter` as `"$FLUTTER_DIR\bin\flutter" doctor --android-licences`.

Comment: After adding it to path, I got error "android-licenses" is unrecognized command.  Issuing "flutter" shows list of command and android-licenses is nowhere to see.

Comment: Try `flutter doctor -h`. It gave me 'android-licences' as a valid option. \n If it's still not present, try updating your flutter.

Comment: Please try running this: `flutter -v doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: Please see UPDATE2 above

Comment: I too had problems installing flutter so I feel you. I already told you what solved it for me so the only thing I could further do is go to the devs. I'm trying to re-open the problem on github ([here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9959)). I will check there from time to time and tell you if anything comes up.
What's weird for me is that `sdkmanager.bat` holds no argument as `--licenses` so maybe flutter is trying to find a different path? Anyhow I'll keep you updated. Have a good one.